# Faster compare method in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

My program imports settings from each file into it's own column, I then loop through all imported columns 1 row at a time to compare data in each row.

If all the cells in each column for the row are equal, I set a results column,row to OK, else it's Check to flag they are not all equal.

Problem is that it takes a long time to populate the results column, is there a faster way? Here is my code:

```
'Auto compare settings and find -1's
For i = 6 To 46

    If Cells(3, i).Value = "Unit" Then
    foundcoltodel = i
    Exit For
    End If


Next i

If foundcoltodel > 6 Then
Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(1, foundcoltodel - 1)).EntireColumn.Select
End If

'auto compare settings from files imported

Dim comparelines() As Integer
Dim LastCol As Integer
    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

Sum = 0

For Each col In Selection.Columns

Sum = Sum + 1


Next
ReDim comparelines(1 To Sum)
z = 1
For Each col In Selection.Columns
comparelines(z) = col.Column
z = z + 1
Next

'Set row 4 back to black

Rows("4:4").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
For i = 7 To 252


If Cells(i, comparelines(1)).Value <> "" Then

For j = 1 To Sum

'set compare columns to red

Cells(4, comparelines(1)).Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

Cells(4, comparelines(j)).Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

'check for equal values per row in each selected column

    If Cells(i, comparelines(1)).Value <> Cells(i, comparelines(j)).Value Then
        allnotequal = True
        Exit For
    Else
        allnotequal = False
    End If
Next j



If allnotequal = True And Cells(i, 5).Value <> "" Then
Cells(i, LastCol - 2).Value = "Check"
Cells(i, LastCol - 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Cells(i, LastCol - 2).Font.Bold = True
End If

If allnotequal = False And Cells(i, 5).Value <> "" Then
Cells(i, LastCol - 2).Value = "Ok"
Cells(i, LastCol - 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Cells(i, LastCol - 2).Font.Bold = True
End If

End If

Next i
```

Comment: Don't use `Select`, turn `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. If it's still really struggling turn `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1

I won't point out every instance, but with these things it's often about how many times you *access* the worksheet. Every time you do something like this: `Cells(,).Value` you are accessing the worksheet.

An example of good practice is to bring all values in a the same time e.g:

```
Dim v as Variant
v = Range("A1:A100").Value
```

Which only accesses the worksheet once, and then loop through the resulting variant array, applying logic of some sort:

```
For i = 1 to 100
    v(i,1) = v(i,1) + 1
Next i
```

And then return to the worksheet in one go (again accessing the worksheet once):

```
Range("A1:A100") = v
```

---

## 2

As Tom says, don't use `Select`. For example:

```
Rows("4:4").Select
    With Selection.Font
```

Could just be

```
With Rows("4:4").Font
```

---

## 3

A couple of `Application` settings might speed things up for you

```
'at beginning of code
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual  

'at end of code
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: The app screen updating and app calc lines at beginning and end of my sub worked amazingly well, now results come in almost instantly, thanks!

Comment: Yes, of all things mentioned, #3 can have the most dramatic effect on time-to-complete.